# How to import CSV and save in database

Tags: go

This is a snippet of the first part of my code

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    file, err := os.Open("Account_balances.csv")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", err)
        return
    }
    defer file.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(file)
    record, err := reader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error", err)
    }

    for value:= range record{ // for i:=0; i<len(record)
        fmt.Println("", record[value])
    }
}
```

I want to write code that saves the CSV file in any database (i.e SQL, SQLite or PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 5):

The Go MySQL driver supports loading from file:

See https://github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#load-data-local-infile-support and https://godoc.org/github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql#RegisterLocalFile.

> RegisterLocalFile adds the given file to the file whitelist, so that
>   it can be used by "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE ". Alternatively
>   you can allow the use of all local files with the DSN parameter
>   'allowAllFiles=true'
>
> ```
> filePath := "/home/gopher/data.csv" mysql.RegisterLocalFile(filePath)
> err := db.Exec("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" + filePath + "' INTO TABLE
> foo") if err != nil { ...
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Each DB engine has different ways for importing CSVs in an optimized way. You should use them instead of writing you own methods for reading CSVs and mass inserting records.

Refs:

MySQL: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html

PgSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html